# Как узнать время начала воспроизведения MP3 Java Jlayer?

Tags: java, jlayer

Библиотека Java Jlayer представляет возможность проигрывания mp3. Для этого можно использовать элемент AdvancedPlayer, которому можно передать параметры начала и окончания воспроизведения.

```
InputStream is=new FileInputStream("File.mp3");
AudioDevice device=new JavaSoundAudioDevice();
AdvancedPlayer ap=new AdvancedPlayer(is,device);
ap.play(int start, int end);
ap.close();
```

Мне нужно воспроизвести композицию не с начала, а с Nной секунды. Но функции play передаются параметры не времени, а [фреймов](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/docs/docs1.0/javazoom/jl/player/advanced/AdvancedPlayer.html).

Каким образом можно узнать номер фрейма, соответствующий некой секунде?

Comment: подскажите те импорты, которые вы использовали

Comment: import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javazoom.jl.player.*;